# Should two entity which have almost same operations combined together or not?

Tags: mysql, database

I don't have much knowledge about databases but here I'm trying to design one. Usually I can design a simple database but this scenario is quite confusing for me.

Let say that I have 3 main entities which is **Organization**, **organization's trainer** and **independent trainer**.

In my system, an organization can add a course and assign organization's trainer to its added course. The organization's trainer cannot add a course but they can only add lessons in it.

While an independent trainer which doesn't have any relation to any organization, can do both, adding course and adding lessons in it.

So my question is, **should the organization's trainer and independent trainer have a combined table like this**:-

```
| Organization |
----------------
| id           |
| name         |



| Trainer |
-----------
| id      |
| org_id  |
| name    |



|    Course    |      |    Lesson    |
----------------      ----------------
| id           |      | id           |
| org_id       |      | ind_train_id |
| ind_train_id |      | org_train_id |
| name         |      | name         |
```

**Or should they be stay apart**:-

```
| Organization |      | Organization's trainer |
----------------      --------------------------
| id           |      | id                     |
| name         |      | org_id                 |
                      | name                   |



| Independent Trainer |
-----------------------
| id                  |
| name                |



|    Course    |      |    Lesson    |
----------------      ----------------
| id           |      | id           |
| org_id       |      | ind_train_id |
| ind_train_id |      | org_train_id |
| name         |      | name         |
```

If they should be combined, what happens to a foreign key in Trainer table (which the trainer is independent)? Can it be null while other (organization's trainer) have their parent key from Organization table? Is there any future problems if this method executed?

If they shouldn't be combined, aren't all column from both tables being redundant (as they will have the same attributes despite the organization foreign key attribute)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will prefer the first approach as its based on the rule that "Foreign key can be null".

And that's why a Foreign key's null concept is designed to keep in mind such situations.

Advantages of using the first approach are that you no need to deal with one extra table and can save a lot of development and maintenance time without any issue.

And yes offcourse make sure there is no Constraints on the Foreign Key.

Comment: What do you mean "_no Constraints on the Foreign Key_"? Null means no data right?

Comment: Null means no data correct. About "no Constraints on the Foreign Key" means once you have a foreign key then don't create constraint on it to make it like not null.